# how to acquire the async function result using C#

Tags: c#, http, async-await

I used a async `httpRequest` in this function:

```cs
public static async Task<HttpContent> RegisterAysnc(Dictionary<String, String> keyValues) 
{
    var multForm = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    StringBuilder urlParameters = new StringBuilder();
    string imgPath = keyValues["avatarSource"];

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    foreach (var kv in keyValues)
    {
        if (kv.Key == "avatarSource")
            continue;

        urlParameters.Append(String.Format("{0}={1}&", kv.Key, kv.Value));
    }

    FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(imgPath);
    multForm.Add(new StreamContent(fs), "photo", Path.GetFileName(imgPath));
    var registerURL = URL.registerUrl + urlParameters.ToString();
    var response = await client.PostAsync(registerURL, multForm);

    return response.Content;
}
```

and this function is called by another function:

```cs
private void RegisterBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ......
    var res = NetWork.RegisterAysnc(parameters);

    Console.WriteLine($"Response is: {res.Result}");
}
```

The server did receive the request from this function, but the `Console.WriteLine()` didn't work; I don't know how to receive the sync result of the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to add await keyword:

```
var res = await NetWork.RegisterAysnc(parameters);
```

If you want to get result synchronously, you can use .GetAwaiter().GetResult()

```
var res = NetWork.RegisterAysnc(parameters).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: (and make your eventhandler `async void` instead of `void`